# C/C++ Is there any cross plataform way of using relative paths?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, sdl, relative-path

I'm programming a little game in SDL and the files are structured like this:

"src/game/" have both .h and .cpp source files.

"data/" have the game files like maps, tilesets, sprites and so on...

to load a sprite for example I would use the following code.

```
spriteLib.loadSprite("data/sprites/sprite-ghost.bmp");
```

to convert this string to an absolute path I have those lines in the first 4 lines of the function:

```
SSprite CSpriteLib::loadSprite(std::string file)
{
    //Converting the file path
    char converted[128];
    realpath(file.c_str(),converted);
    file = converted;
```

But this way the program only compiles under liux so... if anyone knows another way to do that I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few points:

```
char converted[128];
realpath(file.c_str(),converted);
```

1. First of all `realpath` on some operating systems (Solaris) may still return the relative path.
2. Your code contains buffer overflow, it is better to use `canonicalize_file_name` or `char *m=realpath(file.c_str(),0); ... free(m);` - however this is Linux specific. See man `realpath` to see how to use it more or less correctly.

Also how would realpath help you to open your data? If

```
fopen(converted,"r")
```

Works in your case then

```
fopen(file.c_str(),"r")
```

would work as well. It is provided to help removing all symbolic links, etc.

If you need some similar functionality to `realpath`, you may use `GetFullPathName` under Windows, but
it still behaves differently.

Comment: Well I didn't know that fopen would use relative paths, thanks for the tip, but how about the IMG_Load() and SDL_LoadBMP(), they only works with absolute path?

Answer (score 5):

Boost is your friend. Here's a link to the [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm#tutorial) tutorial.

Comment: Wow, that was a fast answer, well I'll have to test it later cuz it's 3:30 am here.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote a tiny class for it:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class CFilePath
{
        typedef std::vector<std::string> TPath;
    public:
        enum EPlatform
        {  
            Windows,
            Unix
        };
        CFilePath(EPlatform p_platform) : m_platform(p_platform) {}
        CFilePath& operator/(const char* p_path)
        {  
            m_path.push_back(p_path);
            return *this;
        }

        std::string GetPath()
        {  
            std::string ret;
            if (m_path.empty())
                return ret;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < m_path.size();)
            {
                ret+=m_path[i];
                i++;
                if (i < m_path.size())
                {  
                    switch (m_platform)
                    {  
                        case Windows:
                            ret+="\\";
                            break;
                        case Unix:
                            ret+="/";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
        operator const char*()
        {
            return GetPath().c_str();
        }
        EPlatform m_platform;

    private:
        std::vector<std::string> m_path;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CFilePath::EPlatform platform = CFilePath::Windows; // variable
    CFilePath path(platform);
    path/"data"/"sprites"/"sprite-ghost.bmp";
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
    path.m_platform = CFilePath::Unix;
    std::cout << path << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

will prints:

```
data\sprites\sprite-ghost.bmp
data/sprites/sprite-ghost.bmp
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is: first, your main program should accept a native filename as an argument that represents where the data for the program live eg

```
C:\program files\mycompany\mygame
```

This passes the responsibility of deciding which data to use off to some other program (such as a bash script or driver or whatever).

Second, define the subparts of the directory space with the data in **unix** format so all filename literals in your program have this format. No ifs and buts, always Unix. Eg:

```
spriteLib.loadSprite("data/sprites/sprite-ghost.bmp");
```

Now write a function which combines the passed in directory name (in native format) with the unix filename translated to native format to get a suitable filename for access. You have already tried to do this but you're using an OS dependent function. Don't. Write it yourself. You want to get this out:

```
C:\program files\mycompany\mygame\data\sprites\sprite-ghost.bmp
```

The method of @Industrial-antidepressant (previously @nice blonde stupid girl) is quite good too, but it's a bit more work.